# Use server.arg results as a function parameter?

Tags: esp8266

I've got an ESP8266 (NodeMCU) and I am trying to understand the ESP8266WebServer library, as how to use the results across functions.

In my setup function, I have the following:

```
   server.on("/marquee", []() {
      varOne = server.arg("baseColor");
      varTwo = server.arg("marqueeColor");
      server.send(200, "text/html", webPage);
      Serial.println("Marquee  activated");
      state = true;
      ledMode = "marquee";  
    });
```

In my loop, I detect the ledMode and if it is set to marquee then it runs the following FastLED function, amongst others:

```
fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, 0xFF0000);
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I go from taking a hex color code of say `FF0000` from the URL parameter, and use that in my `fill_solid` function.

server.arg stores get the parameter as a string, so I am not sure what needs to be done.  Also, using a variable name in place of the Hex code in the `fill_solid` function results in an error due to not expecting the variable

Comment: What argument types does `fill_solid()` take, please?

Answer (score 1):

> server.arg stores get the parameter as a string, so I am not sure what needs to be done.

The parameter needs to be converted to an uint32_t (and then to a CRGB or CHSV struct). The simplest way is to use the C library function [strtoul](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaea44aa48bda8261f794dcb2d1e7ab2b2)

```
uint32_t color = strtoul(arg, NULL, 16);
```

This can be improved so that it checks that a number was scanned, etc.

Cheers!